# pyqt: create a Qwidget through a function

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer, qwidget, qframe

I want to insert a QLabel in a frame of my GUI.
If i do it directly in the init function it works:

```
class MyApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('MyGui.ui',self) # <<< this is the GUI made with QtDesigner
        
        LB1 = QLabel('MyLabel',self.myFrame) # <<< this is the destination frame
        ...
```

but if a do the same thing through a function it seems not working:

```
def MYFUNCTION(self):
    LB1 = QLabel('MyLabel',self.myFrame)
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: If you add a widget *after* the parent window is shown, you need to call `LB1.show()`.